# Remove file that is not pushed yet

Tags: git, github

I have a file that contain a change that should not go to server. 
I have run following commands:

```
git add file
git commit -m "Bug Fix XXXXX"
```

But yet to be fired the command `git push origin develop`

I want to revert the changes to last commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just that file you want to revert, you can use `git checkout <filename>`. This won't change your previous commit though, it will just say that there is a new change to that file.

If you want to revert the entire commit, just use `git reset HEAD^`. The `HEAD^` means parent of the current tip of your branch (should be your previous *good* commit).

If you'd already pushed, in the future you could use `git revert`.

Comment: `git reset HEAD^` will make the current branch point to the commit just prior to your change.  `git revert <commit>` will commit a new change that reverses your mistake.

Comment: @Daniel Yep, but if the OP hasn't pushed, they may as well not push that commit/revert. In my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If u need to make changes to that particular file instead of commit revert you can

`git checkout <file_name>`

Make necessary changes to it.

`git add <file_name>`

`git commit --amend` //This amends the latest commit

The above command can be used to modify the commit message if required.

`git push origin develop`